# Access to the path is denied ( file.delete )

Tags: c#

OK, I made a program that when the program launches it will remove an existing DLL file once the program is updated.

When the program launches for the first time after the update it will extract a .zip file which contains all the updated files.

Before I tried to delete the file in question that is causing the program to mess up I got this error

[Before i added in file.delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ8Xd.png)

So when I got that error I was like ok I will delete the file so when it exacts the zip. it will just add it back

then I got this error when I added in the file.delete

[error once added in file.delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRra5.png)

and I have no idea now how to fix any of this I been trying all day and I just can't find a way around it and it's driving me crazy

Because it worked fine on 7.

Code I currently have.

```
        public void test()
    {
        String TargetDirectory = updatepath;
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(updatepath + "\\elfenliedtopfan5_weapons.zip"))
        {
            File.SetAttributes(updatepath1, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(updatepath1);
            zip.ExtractExistingFile = ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently;
            zip.ExtractAll(TargetDirectory);
        }
    }
```

but I get an error access to the path is denied

Comment: it sounds like the file is open somewhere.

Comment: yeah its strange i never had this issue on win 7 only on win 10 not tried on win 8.1 but its really hard to get it to replace it it is kinda used 

tutupdater.dll is used to call update but each time u bulid my program it re adds that so im sure in each update it needs the new dll.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that makes sense would be that you need to elevate your privileges.Go to your /bin and run the .exe as Admin, see if it works.

Comment: Yeah i have done running it as admin that was one of the first things i have attempted to do to fix it.